# Pythagorean theorem for operators

Tags: matrices, inequality, convex-analysis

For numbers $a,b\in\mathbb{R}_+$, we have that
$$\sqrt{a^2+b^2} \leq a+b.$$

Can we extend this to operators? In other words, given positive semi-definite operators $A,B$ (of same size), is it the case that
\begin{align}
\sqrt{A^2+B^2} \leq A + B
\end{align}
where the ordering is the matrix ordering ($Q\geq0$ means $Q$ is positive semi-definite)?

I have been looking into [this note](http://www.ueltschi.org/AZschool/notes/EricCarlen.pdf), where they show many useful results regarding operator monotonicity and convexity, though could not find a good tool for answering this one.

**Remark**: there exist semi-definite positive matrices $A,B$ that result in $AB+BA$ be non-positive (i.e. $AB+BA$ can have negative eigen-values).

(Not sure if the title is a good one! The reason behind choosing it is that given a right-angled triangle with sides $a,b$ the hypothenuse is $\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$, and from triangle inequality it follows that $\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\leq a+b$).

Comment: No. Hint: what if A and B are projections?

Comment: Hmmm.. it is not straightforward to see the counterexample. If they commute (in other words project into orthogonal subspaces), it holds with equality.

Comment: What if they don't commute?

Comment: It is true though that that $\text{trace}\Big(\sqrt{A^2+B^2}\Big) \leq \text{trace}\Big(A + B\Big)$.  I gave a proof here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1880398/inequality-of-square-root-inside-trace-norm/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

Towards a counterexample, note that if $A$ and $B$ are orthogonal projections ($A^2 = A$, $B^2 = B$), the inequality rewrites to $$ \sqrt{A + B} \leq A + B.$$ Since $\sqrt{A + B}$ and $A + B$ commute, this is equivalent to the squared inequality $$ A + B \leq (A + B)^2 = A^2 + B^2 + A B + BA = A + B + A B + BA \\ \Leftrightarrow 0 \leq A B + B A.$$ It is hence enough to find orthogonal projections $A$ and $B$ such that $A B + B A$ is not positive semidefinite. One such pair is $$A = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}, B = \begin{bmatrix} \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} \\ \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} \end{bmatrix} \Rightarrow A B + B A = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & \frac{1}{2} \\ \frac{1}{2} & 0 \end{bmatrix}.$$ These matrices in fact appear more or less in the Example 2.2 of the linked note.

One can actually prove that if $A$ and $B$ are orthogonal projections, $A B + B A$ is positive semidefinite only if $A$ and $B$ commute, so any noncommuting projection pair works as a counterexample to the original problem.

Answer (score 0):

**Partial Answer**: The following analysis works if it is true that $A^2 \geq B^2 \implies A \geq B$, which I'm not sure myself.

Let's consider the squared version of the problem (which may or may not be equivalent to the original),
$$A^2 + B^2 \leq (A+B)^2$$

The positive semi-definite condition can be imposed as,
\begin{align}
 &x^T \left[(A+B)^2 - A^2 - B^2\right]x \geq 0 \qquad \forall x \in \mathbb{R}^n \\
&x^T \left(AB + BA\right)x \geq 0 \qquad \forall x \in \mathbb{R}^n
\end{align}

Hence, $AB + BA$ must also be positive semi-definite. But as the OP remarked, this is not always true. This implies that the OP's original relation ($\sqrt{A^2+B^2} \leq A + B$) is unlikely to always hold true.

Comment: This is not true (your assumption). See example 2.2 of the note I mentioned in the post.